# Count function Python

Tags: python

I want to make a function that does the same thing as count, 
without using count.
Something like this:

```
>>> count('mama ma emu a ema ma mamu', 'ma ')
4
>>> count('mama ma emu a ema ma mamu', 'am')
2
```

How could I acheive this?

Comment: Simply iterate through it, you can it urself, I am sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I thought I'd add an iterative approach where you loop through the string as it would be easier to understand.

Try this:

```
def count(string, substring):

    count = 0

    for i in range(len(string) - len(substring) + 1):
        if string[i: i + len(substring)] == substring:
            count += 1

    return count
```

Essentially, I'm iterating through the possible values of `i`, where `i` is the starting index of each substring which is of the same length as the substring entered. Then, I'm simply checking if each possible substring of the correct length is equivalent to the substring entered. If so, I increment my `count` by 1.

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: I can't upvote,because i haven't got enough reputation. And i accept this solution(click on the pipe),i hope it means accept,sorry if i did something badly,but i'm new here.

Comment: @JozefŠprlák You've done everything fine  Thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

Is using `re` allowed?

```
import re

def count(text, s):
    return len(re.findall(s, text))

print(count('mama ma emu a ema ma mamu', 'ma '))
print(count('mama ma emu a ema ma mamu', 'am'))
```

Prints:

```
4
2
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try this list comprehension:

```
def count(s,ss):
    return sum(1 for e in range(len(s)-len(ss)+1) if s[e:e+len(ss)]==ss)
```